# Neo4j 2 Cypher fuzzy search

Tags: cypher, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2 REST API and I have the ability to add plugins.

I have an entity in my database with the label 'Entity' and name 'United Kingdom'.

How do I execute a fuzzy search to find this entity.

I would like to be able to find it using queries like

- United
- Kingdom
- Uniter Kingdom
- United Kinjdom

So the `.*<query>.*` won't do it.

I notice there was support for something like this in previous versions.

```
start n = node:index("name : 'United Kinjom'~0.2") return n
```

But this doesn't appear to work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still works. Adding fulltext search to the automatic new schema indexes is on the roadmap. Until then you can still use the "legacy" indexes.

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

Comment: is this still in the roadmap. When is full text indices expectef?