# Fuzzy neo4j relationships

Tags: neo4j

I want to do something in neo4j that I hope will work ok: I want to make "fuzzy" path matches; the links will sometimes count as a relationship, and sometimes not, depending on the query.

Here's an example: let's say I have a (p:Person)-[:HAS]->(n:Name). A search has found a Person (say, by phone number). I want to go from this Person to other Persons with similar names, to get their phone numbers. Also, I want the similarity to be adjustable, so the user might ask to match very similar names, or not very similar names.

I could get the first person's name, and then do a search against other names with some lucene patterns - this is easy enough, but it means doing a full lucene search on the Name values, which in my use case is not ideal as I think it might be a bit slow (there are very many names - let's say a billion, remembering this is just an example). I hope there is a better way.

One approach I can imagine is having a "similarity" relationship between Names. Whenever a new Name node is added, we check for similar names and link them (creating these relationships would be slow, but we could push it onto a batch process, and it's ok if it takes some minutes). We would only link names that were fairly similar (so the number of links would hopefully not get too large). I suppose we could then craft a query on this, matching similarities greater than my threshold. Something like this:

```
MATCH   (p1:Person {phone:"555-234234"})-->(n1:Name)-[s:SIMILAR]->(n2:Name)-->(p2:Person)
WHERE   s.matchLevel >=2
RETURN  p2.phone;
```

Is this approach better or worse than just doing the lucene search? Has anyone else wanted to do something like this?

Also, based on the suggestion at http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/24/neo4j-qualifying-relationships.html, I believe I'll be better off having many relationships (SIMILAR_1, SIMILAR_2 ..) instead of using a "match level" attribute on my relationship.

BTW, I know there are many *similar* questions to this (eg. [Neo4j 2 Cypher fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887087/neo4j-2-cypher-fuzzy-search)), but afaik this *exact* question isn't on stackoverflow (and I have looked).

Comment: I'm thinking that this isn't something that you could do with Cypher (I'm always happy to be corrected).  You could, however, build an unmanaged extension for Neo4j which would allow you to make custom traversals with Java which can be setup and returned via HTTP endpoints: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Comment: Also note that in 3.0 (currently in beta/release candidate) you can make stored procedures which you can access via Cypher: http://jexp.de/blog/2016/02/neo4j-3-0-stored-procedures/